# Start elevated subprocess from C++ code and communicate with it via stdin/stdout

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I need to start a subprocess with elevated privileges from C++ code. I'm not familiar with Windows APIs at all, and from cursory googling I found out that
a) to start an elevated process I need to use `ShellExecute` with the `runas` verb.
b) to communicate with subprocess via stdin/stdout I have to use `CreateProcess`

But I haven't found a way to do both at the same time.

Additionally, I need to

- either get a callback when the process finishes, or poll it to see whether it's still running
- check its return code

As I said, I'm completely unfamiliar with Windows API, so could someone point me to the right functions?

Comment: you need set `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` in `SHELLEXECUTEINFO.fMask` and use `SHELLEXECUTEINFO.hProcess` with some wait functions and finally call `GetExitCodeProcess` and `CloseHandle` - about stdin/stdout - this is impossible by design with elevated process

Comment: Time to graduate from "cursory googling" to actually studying the documentation. This website is not a replacement for that act. Start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30970718/103167

Comment: I suggest to read up on [named pipes API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx) which could be used quite similar to stdin/stdout. [Example code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365799(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: See [`CreateProcessElevated()`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19165/Vista-UAC-The-Definitive-Guide), which supports starting an elevated process while redirecting std(in|out|err) using named pipes.